# Oracle compare lists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables `AAA` and `BBB` in `Oralce DB`.

```
Table AAA
'aaa'
'aaa'
'aaa'
'bbb'
'bbb'

Table BBB
'aaa'
'aaa'
'bbb'
'bbb'
'bbb'
```

I need to compare by following actions with these tables:

```
AAA - BBB
```

result: '`aaa`'

```
BBB - AAA
```

result: '`bbb`'

```
BBB intersect AAA

result:
'aaa'
'aaa'
'bbb'
'bbb'
```

Standart operations `minus, union, intersect` did not help me

Comment: Your result of `intersect` ist **wrong**, it returns only two rows with `aaa` and `bbb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number analytical function as following:

**AAA - BBB**

```
SELECT RESULT FROM 
(SELECT COLA AS RESULT,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLA ORDER BY 1) AS RN  
 FROM AAA 
 MINUS  
 SELECT COLB,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLB ORDER BY 1) AS RN  
 FROM BBB)
```

Same for **BBB - AAA** but with queries interchanged.

```
SELECT RESULT FROM 
(SELECT COLB AS RESULT,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLB ORDER BY 1) AS RN  
 FROM BBB 
 MINUS  
 SELECT COLA,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLA ORDER BY 1) AS RN  
 FROM AAA)
```

For **BBB intersect AAA**

```
SELECT RESULT FROM 
(SELECT COLB AS RESULT,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLB ORDER BY 1) AS RN  
 FROM BBB 
 INTERSECT
 SELECT COLA,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLA ORDER BY 1) AS RN  
 FROM AAA)
```

Cheers!!

Comment: SQL> select * from AAA;

COLA
-----
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb
aaa

SQL> select * from BBB;

COLB
-----
bbb
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb

SQL>

Comment: SELECT RESULT FROM
(SELECT COLA AS RESULT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLA) AS RN
 FROM AAA
 MINUS
 SELECT COLB,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLB) AS RN
 FROM BBB)

ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification

Comment: I've got an error: ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification

Comment: Done. that was missing!!

Comment: Please can you explain it?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLA ORDER BY 1)

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()` analytic function such as :

```
with AAA as
(
 select 'aaa' as str from dual union all
 select 'aaa' from dual union all
 select 'aaa' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual     
), BBB as
(
 select 'aaa' as str from dual union all
 select 'aaa' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual     
), t as
(
  select row_number() over (order by 1) rn, str from BBB
  minus
  select row_number() over (order by 1) rn, str from AAA
)
select str 
  from t

STR
---
bbb
```

and then reverse the order of the tables.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3078ac21a7d7678d0b5968841db06cc8)</kbd>

*If minus is applied direclty, then it removes all the occurences of the returning rows even if they're duplicates. Because those string type values are identical for both of the sets.*

Comment: with AAA(str) as
(
 select 'aaa' from dual union all
 select 'aaa' from dual union all
 select 'aaa' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual
), BBB(str) as
(
 select 'aaa' from dual union all
 select 'aaa' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual union all
 select 'bbb' from dual
), t as
(
  select row_number() over (order by 1) rn, str from BBB
  minus
  select row_number() over (order by 1) rn, str from AAA
)
select str
  from t

ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing

Comment: SQL> select * from AAA;

COLA
-----
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb
aaa

SQL> select * from BBB;

COLB
-----
bbb
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb

SQL>

Comment: I've got an error: ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing

Comment: well, then use the edited version of the sample data sets (*both in the answer and the demo*), seems you're using DB version prior to 11.2 @Ferrum3000 .